# Handling exception when Worksheet is not present

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm trying to handle the exception when Worksheet is not present using this code:

```
int k = blYear.SelectedIndex;
ExcelWorksheet currentWorkSheet;

try
{
    currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[k + 1];
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("La hoja de trabajo no existe en el archivo de Excel", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    btnCargarExcel.Enabled = true;
    blYear.Enabled = true;
    filePath.Text = "";
}
```

But I'm getting this errors:

- if I try to compile this error appears

  > Error    1   Use of unassigned local variable 'currentWorkSheet' d:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ExcelDBUserControl.cs 71  46  CMApp
- if I omit the error and continue building then I get this other

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio
>   --------------------------- Source file: D:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ExcelDBUserControl.cs
>
> Module:
>   d:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\CMApp.exe
>
> Process: [4944] CMApp.vshost.exe
>
> The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you
>   like the debugger to use it anyway?
>   Yes   No
>
> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146232969   Message=The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>          at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets.get_Item(Int32 PositionID)
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.ExcelDBUserControl.btnCargarExcel_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ExcelDBUserControl.cs:line
>   66
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in d:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   20
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

what's the proper way to handle this?

**EDIT for 1st error**
Ok, seeing the error about the undeclared var I made some modifications to my code and now is this:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;
    ExcelWorksheet currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

    if (workbook != null)
    {
        if (workbook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
        {

            int k = blYear.SelectedIndex;

            try
            {
                currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[k + 1];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La hoja de trabajo no existe en el archivo de Excel", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                btnCargarExcel.Enabled = true;
                blYear.Enabled = true;
                filePath.Text = "";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But this has a problem, even if **Exception** is launched the first worksheet is loaded because of this `ExcelWorksheet currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();` and this is not what I want to achieve. If I define the var as `ExcelWorksheet currentWorkSheet;` and set the value inside the first condition then the same error:

> Error    1   Use of unassigned local variable 'currentWorkSheet' d:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ExcelDBUserControl.cs 71  46  CMApp

appears so I don't know how to handle this, I'm stucked here

Comment: Where is the Instance of the WorkBook, or Excel Application? try looking at this link for a simple fix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111935/c-sharp-and-excel-interop

Comment: @DJKRAZE I made some edit to my post and no, the link you leave me doesn't help

Comment: Does `ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = null` work?

Comment: @HjalmarZ yes, it does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated code is much better. Essentially you need to decide from a business logic/UI behaviour what you want to happen when there isn't a current worksheet. You could set currentWorksheet = null in the exception handler (or before the try) and then add extra logic outside the catch to do... whatever you want to do if currentWorksheet is null. Or just put a return statement in the catch so none of the following code is executed. It's up to you.

Comment: thanks, following your suggestions I do the homework and get things working, I'll add the solution to the first post in case another people has the same problem